# How to get list of files and folders from Google Drive on my own website using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, google-drive-api

I have a case where i need to display user's google drive data on my own website. how to do this. i have setup Google's Example DriRdit.

Comment: you need to use apis if provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is authentication. You can use Google's own example detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php) which runs you through the entire procedure of doing that.

Once you have authentication complete, you can do the following:
Register for an API key [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

You can now send an HTTP GET request using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in PHP to the URL `https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/files/list`. An AJAX request to the page wouldn't work as the page wouldn't be a part of your domain.
You need to send your requests with the following parameters.

> maxResults    integer  Maximum number of files to return.
>
> pageToken string   Page token for files.
>
> q string   Query string for searching files.

The final request might look like

```
file_get_contents("https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/files/list?maxResults=".$maxResults."&pageToken=".$pageToken");
```

Link: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: Thanks, i have setup google's example DriEdit and also registerd for an API key. now i am able to authenticate user but it redirects me on redirect uri and display nothing.

Comment: Did you issue the GET request? You should use the following format https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#making_authorized_api_requests